# Getting JNA to work with Java => C#?

Tags: c#, java, jna

I've written a lot of code in a C# library, which I now need to call from Java.

I saw it recommended on SO to use [JNA](http://jna.java.net), but I'm having trouble even getting out of the starting blocks; the documentation there is very sketchy.

Firstly, it only appears to show you how to connect to the Native C library, which is no good to me; I want to connect to my own library.  The code sample there shows:

```
// This is the standard, stable way of mapping, which supports extensive
// customization and mapping of Java to native types.
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary)
        Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c"),
                           CLibrary.class);

    void printf(String format, Object... args);
}
```

I want to connect to my library (MyLibrary.dll), and call a static method on `MyNamespace.MyClass` whose C# signature is:

```
public static string HelloWorld(string p)
```

So what parameters to I give to `Native.loadLibrary()`?

That's just for "Hello World".  What if I want to return an object?  Let's say `MyClass` also has a static method

```
public static MyClass GetInstance()
```

How would I call that using JNA?  I guess I would have to define an interface in Java that matches the C# `MyClass` interface... but would it have to be exhaustive, i.e. for every public member of `MyClass` I would have to declare a method in an `IMyClass` interface in Java?  Or can I just leave out the interfaces I don't care about?

Any sample code would be gratefully welcomed!

Comment: JNA and C# will not mix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You won't be able to call directly into your C# code from Java.  JNA will only be able to access a native library (C or C++).  However you could enable COM Interop in your library and link the 2 together with a native wrapper.  I.e. it would look some thing like:

`Java --(JNA)-->  C/C++ --(COM Interop)--> C#`

There are a couple of alternatives:

- Make the C# a stand alone command line app and have the Java code send/receive data from it using stdin/stdout ([ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) can help you here).
- Run the C# as a stand alone app with some form of platform neutral messaging protocol to communicate between the 2 of them, e.g. HTTP, AMQP.

Comment: this sounds like a lot of pain to track

Comment: @mbx: it is what it is, but Michael Barker does a good job of succinctly describing the options. +1 to him.

Comment: @Hovercraft - Agreed. It's not the answer I *wanted*, but it is an answer, and I'll accept it.  In practice though I'll probably have to buy some other solution like JNBridge.

Comment: actually, while not 1:1 related with your question, it might help to know that there are open-source cross-compilers that allow you to compile the C/C++ "middleware" on platforms like Linux to run C# stuff on WIndows.

Answer (score 1):

This Nugget is super easy to use and works perfectly. https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports

You need Visual Studio 2012 (Express works fine).
Once installed, just add  `[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]` before any static function you want to export. That's it!

**Example:**

**C#**

```
[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
public static int YourFunction(string data)
{
     /*Your code here*/
     return 1;
}
```

**Java**

Add the import at the top:

```
   import com.sun.jna.Native;
```

Add the interface in your class. Its your C# function name preceded by the letter "I":

```
  public interface IYourFunction extends com.sun.jna.Library
    {
       public int YourFunction(String tStr);
    };
```

Call your DLL where you need it in your class:

```
IYourFunction iYourFunction = (IYourFunction )Native.loadLibrary("full or relative path to DLL withouth the .dll extention", IYourFunction.class);//call JNA
        System.out.println("Returned: " + IYourFunction.YourFunction("some parameter"));
```

Comment: This process fails when C# dll has dependencies dlls. ex: if the dll has some external references it will crash

Answer (score 0):

You can use Caffeine for this http://caffeine.berlios.de/site/documentation/