# Using C# dll in java

Tags: c#, java, dll

Im trying to use external .dll file coding in c# ,in my Java application , what I know about the dll that it contains interfaces with functions we can use ,I can load the dll to my java application , but how i can use the interfaces within it ? I dont know how JNI can help in this case .Please help .

Comment: JNI is for native libraries only, not managed code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll need to use a Java/COM bridge such as [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/), or [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) (you'll likely have to write a bridge, since JNA is for *native* access only).

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6009272/12960) for more details.

Comment: we can use JNA java 7 not 6 right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create native exports from your C# DLL using a project template written by [Robert Giesecke](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/csharpprojecttemplateforunmanagedexports). This allows you to create native C-style API exports in your C# DLL, and call them from Java or almost any other language. Scroll down to the bottom of the page for the Unmanaged Export Library file.

Alternatively, you could use [`ComVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) to create a COM class and access it from Java.

Comment: should I put the class which is using ComVisible in dll file and then using it in java app?if so , how i should import it and call it?

Comment: Yes. Here's [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3fd4a20.aspx). You'll need to mark the DLL as COM Visible too. Have a read through [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092553/turn-a-simple-c-sharp-dll-into-a-com-interop-component) for some more info. Brian Agnew's answer covers using COM in Java.