# Error looking up for: '' The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: java, c#, jna

I am trying to use C# dll function in java. I got the error that function cannot be found, however, the dll was found and successfully loaded.

While I was searching for a problem I found that sometimes a compiler mangle the symbols and the whole function name to something like 'myFunction@32' instead of 'myFunction'. Unfortunately that wasn't my issue.

```
public interface IConectorT extends Library {
boolean DeleteCustomObjectRecord(String company, String username, String password, int cdoId, 
String cdoName, int[] cdoRecordIds);


IConectorT INSTANCE = (IConectorT) Native.loadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Eloqua API", 
IConectorT.class, new HashMap() {
    {
        put("DeleteCustomObjectRecord","_DeleteCustomObjectRecord@32");
    }
});
}
```

I have tried @64, @32, @16 etc. Also tried adding "_" as prefix. 
I have also tried absolute path with ".dll" and without, relative path the same. (But loading is not a problem)

I tried a little update and now it returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Main.Main.DeleteCustomObjectRecord(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava
/lang/String;[I)Z
at Main.Main.DeleteCustomObjectRecord(Native Method)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, JNA is for *native* library only.  You will need to write a C/C++ wrapper for your C# library before accessing it from Java.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009235/getting-jna-to-work-with-java-c/6009272#6009272)

Comment: Are you using a C/C++ dll ?

Comment: C# so maybe you are right, can you advice me how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378826/How-to-wrap-a-Csharp-library-for-use-in-Java  . You could also use standalone command line C# program and access it with `ProcessBuilder` or HTTP server like proposed by Michael Barker@ in the post I linked in my first response.